# Problem with alignment inside a table and its notes

Tags: tables, spacing, notes, threeparttable

to explain my problem, please look at this table:

[image]

1) I want to bring the red part closer to the middle, so that the three columns are more centered.

2) I want to align the blue part in one vertical line. I tried to use `{flalign*}`, but this aligns the equations with the column on the top, and not the "Profitability calculation".

This is the code that I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\small
\caption[xxx]{Example calculation for a two-product SSNIP test \citep{QuantTech}.}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{20em} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7em}}    
\hlineB{3}
  & Product 1 & Product 2  \\ \hline
Margin & 10\% & 20\% \\
Diversion ratio & 0.29 & 0.5 \\ 
Own-price elasticity of demand & 2 & 4 \\ 
Ratio of prices $p_2 / p_1$ & 1 & 1 \\                       
\hlineB{3}
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\item Profitability calculation:\\
\begin{align*}
\frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} \overset{?}{\leqslant} \frac{1}{\eta_{11}(p_1,p_2.\ldots,p_J)} + \frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_2} \frac{p_2}{p_1} DR_{12}, \qquad 0.1 \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + 0.2 \times 1 \times 0.29 = 0.56
 \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_1} \overset{?}{\leqslant} \frac{1}{\eta_{22}(p_1,p_2.\ldots,p_J)} + \frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} \frac{p_1}{p_2} DR_{21}, \qquad 0.2 \leqslant \frac{1}{4} + 0.1 \times 1 \times 0.5 = 0.30
\end{align*}

\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{ExampleSSNIP}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'm grateful for any help - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want your table to fill the text width (you shouldn't, unless you're doing two column typesetting), at least don't use `\small`.

You don't need `threeparttable`, in this case. Just use `\raggedright`.

I used `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. You can use `mathptmx` (but the results are poorer); never ever use `times` if you have math in your document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption[xxx]{Example calculation for a two-product SSNIP test \citep{QuantTech}.}
\label{ExampleSSNIP}   

\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\hspace{.1\textwidth}\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l c c
  @{\hspace{.1\textwidth}}
}
\toprule
                               & Product 1 & Product 2 \\
\midrule
Margin                         & 10\%      & 20\%      \\
Diversion ratio                & 0.29      & 0.5       \\
Own-price elasticity of demand & 2         & 4         \\
Ratio of prices $p_2 / p_1$    & 1         & 1         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip

\raggedright
Profitability calculation:\\[\medskipamount]
$\begin{alignedat}{2}
\frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} &\overset{?}{\leqslant} 
  \frac{1}{\eta_{11}(p_1,p_2.\dots,p_J)} + \frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_2} \frac{p_2}{p_1} DR_{12},
  &\qquad& 0.1 \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + 0.2 \times 1 \times 0.29 = 0.56
\\
\frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_1} &\overset{?}{\leqslant} 
  \frac{1}{\eta_{22}(p_1,p_2.\dots,p_J)} + \frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} \frac{p_1}{p_2} DR_{21},
  &\qquad& 0.2 \leqslant \frac{1}{4} + 0.1 \times 1 \times 0.5 = 0.30
\end{alignedat}$

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `boldrule` I used `booktabs`. Adjust the amount of spacing before the first column and after the last one; but my advice is *not* to artificially expand tables, particularly if they contain such small amount of columns.

Note that `\ldots` should be `\dots`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg, I deleted my old comment since the package download works now. Your solution is perfect!  I have a question though: My reasoning for wanting to make the table `\textwidth` is that the notes below it make it almost as wide as the text anyways. So, instead of leaving some space on the left and right, I thought I will rather make it as wide as the text to make it better looking. Since you say this is wrong however, how can I make it only as wide as is necessary? I tried to remove the `\textwidth`, but then am faced with "Illegal unit of measure" .

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution, with the `flushleft` option for tablenotes, and the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` to wrap the `align*`environment, which has the effect to use the | fleqn`option from`amsmath` locally, for one group of equations.

I also replaced the obsolete `times` package with `newtx`, which uses a  Times clone (TeX Gyre Termes).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nccmath}


 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \small
  \caption[xxx]{Example calculation for a two-product SSNIP test.}% \citep{QuantTech}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{20em} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7em}}
      \hlineB{3}
                                     & Product 1 & Product 2 \\ \hline
      Margin & 10\,\% & 20\,\% \\
      Diversion ratio & 0.29 & 0.5 \\
      Own-price elasticity of demand & 2 & 4 \\
      Ratio of prices $p_2/p_1 $ & 1 & 1 \\
      \hlineB{3}
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
      \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
      \item Profitability calculation:
      \begin{fleqn}[\fontdimen2\font]
        \begin{align*}
          \frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} & \overset{?}{\leqslant} \frac{1}{\eta_{11}(p_1,p_2.\ldots,p_J)} + \frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_2} \frac{p_2}{p_1} DR_{12}, & 0.1 & \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + 0.2 × 1 × 0.29 = 0.56 \\%
          \frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_1} & \overset{?}{\leqslant} \frac{1}{\eta_{22}(p_1,p_2.\ldots,p_J)} + \frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} \frac{p_1}{p_2} DR_{21}, & 0.2 & \leqslant \frac{1}{4} + 0.1 × 1 × 0.5 = 0.30
        \end{align*}
      \end{fleqn}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \label{ExampleSSNIP}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However I suggest this code, based on `tabulary`,  which looks niver in my opinio:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx, tabulary}
\usepackage{nccmath}


 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \small\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \caption[xxx]{Example calculation for a two-product SSNIP test.}% \citep{QuantTech}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{L>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8em}@{}}%p{20em} \hlineB{3}
                                     & Product 1 & Product 2 \\ \hlineB{3}
      Margin & 10\,\% & 20\,\% \\
      Diversion ratio & 0.29 & 0.5 \\
      Own-price elasticity of demand & 2 & 4 \\
      Ratio of prices $p_2 / p_1$ & 1 & 1 \\
      \hlineB{3}
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
      \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
      \item Profitability calculation:
      \begin{fleqn}[\fontdimen2\font]
        \begin{align*}
          \frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} & \overset{?}{\leqslant} \frac{1}{\eta_{11}(p_1,p_2.\ldots,p_J)} + \frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_2} \frac{p_2}{p_1} DR_{12}, & 0.1 & \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + 0.2 \times 1 \times 0.29 = 0.56 \\%
          \frac{p_2 - c_2}{p_1} & \overset{?}{\leqslant} \frac{1}{\eta_{22}(p_1,p_2.\ldots,p_J)} + \frac{p_1 - c_1}{p_1} \frac{p_1}{p_2} DR_{21}, & 0.2 & \leqslant \frac{1}{4} + 0.1 \times 1 \times 0.5 = 0.30
        \end{align*}
      \end{fleqn}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \label{ExampleSSNIP}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution and also the corrections! What is the point of `[\fontdimen2\font]` though? From what I saw, it doesn't do anything.  

Going back to my first question: How can I move the first column (not the notes below it!) to the right? Ideally, I would want to treat the three columns as group, so that as a whole the three columns lie at the center of the table. I can provide an example from the original source if needed.

Comment: `\fontdimen2\font` is the interword space in the current font. I had  to use it because although  `\item` in table notes is empty, there is nonetheless this space in front of ‘Profitability’, so I had to put it as a display indent via the optional argument of the `fleqn` environment, to ensure vertical alignment. As to your first requirement, one might reduce the width of the first column, but I'm not not sure I fully understand. It would be clearer,  I guess, with an example.